# Types of Thread Pools in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

What are the types of thread pools in java. I need to implement a robust multi-threaded application which uses heavy computation, which thread pool should I use?

Comment: Take a look at the methods of [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for the types of thread pool. You may also be interested in [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are various thread pools in java:

- Single Thread Executor : A thread pool with only one thread. So all the submitted tasks will be executed sequentially. Method : `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`
- Cached Thread Pool : A thread pool that creates as many threads it needs to execute the task in parrallel. The old available threads will be reused for the new tasks. If a thread is not used during 60 seconds, it will be terminated and removed from the pool. Method : `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`
- Fixed Thread Pool : A thread pool with a fixed number of threads. If a thread is not available for the task, the task is put in queue waiting for an other task to ends. Method : `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`
- Scheduled Thread Pool : A thread pool made to schedule future task. Method : `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`
- Single Thread Scheduled Pool : A thread pool with only one thread to schedule future task. Method : `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`

Answer (score 4):

There are many types ;)

There is, for instance, [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). This is the "basic" implementation which allows to submit tasks etc. You will probably want to use [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to obtain a new one, since it has static factory methods for the most common scenarios.

Since Java 7 you also have [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Also have a look at [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), since this is a very convenient class to build individual threads.

Answer (score 4):

This shows good animations on the diffrent concurrency constructs, may this will help you choose

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaconcurrenta/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Each common `ExecutorService` is explained and you will probably find one that fits your needs among them.

Answer (score 3):

You can read more about ThreadPoolExecutors here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

However, it might be a good idea to look at the ForkJoinTask API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html