# What are the different types of pooling in java?

Tags: java, jndi

I was asked this question in an interview , where I could only answered jndi and am not sure if there's anything else like object pooling , thread pooling . Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, a pool is a set of resources that are kept ready to use, rather than acquired on use and released afterwards. In this context, resources can refer to system resources such as file handles, which are external to a process, or internal resources such as objects (read more).

In Java there are

1. JDBC/JNDI Connection Pooling (for more details [see](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html))
2. Thread Pooling (for more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186206/types-of-thread-pools-in-java))
3. Object Pool Design Pattern (for more details see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern))
4. Memory Pool (might or might not apply to Java)

Expanding on Thread Pooling you can have

There are various thread pools in java:

**Single Thread Executor** : A thread pool with only one thread. So all the submitted tasks will be executed sequentially. Method : Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Cached Thread Pool : A thread pool that creates as many threads it needs to execute the task in parrallel. The old available threads will be reused for the new tasks. If a thread is not used during 60 seconds, it will be terminated and removed from the pool. Method : Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

**Fixed Thread Pool** : A thread pool with a fixed number of threads. If a thread is not available for the task, the task is put in queue waiting for an other task to ends. Method : Executors.newFixedThreadPool()

**Scheduled Thread Pool** : A thread pool made to schedule future task. Method : Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()

**Single Thread Scheduled Pool** : A thread pool with only one thread to schedule future task. Method : Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

In terms of **Memory Pool** I am not entirely sure whether Garbage collection and/or other features of Java that does the job of memory allocation (similar to malloc, calloc, etc) make use of Memory pool or not.